# Normalizers over centralizers of Levi subalgebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, nilpotent-orbits

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a simple Lie algebra and $e$ a  nilpotent element of $\mathfrak g$. Using Jacobson-Morozov theorem, there exist a nilpotent element $f$ and a semisimple element $h$ such that $\{e,h,f\}$ is a $sl_2$ triples.  Then consider the centralizer  $\mathfrak g^h:=\{q\in \mathfrak g:[h,q]=0\}$ of $h$. Then $\mathfrak g^h$ is a Levi sublgebra of $\mathfrak g$. Let $G$ be the adjoint group of $\mathfrak g$. Then we can define the normalizers $N:=\{n\in G:Ad_n\mathfrak g^h\subseteq \mathfrak g^h\}$ and the ceneralizers $C:=\{c\in G:Ad_c q=q, ~ \forall q\in\mathfrak g\}$.  In the case the nilpotent element $e$ is regular, it is known that $N/C$ is the underline Weyl group $W$ of $\mathfrak g$. For other types of nilpotent elements, $N/C$ must contains $W$. Are  there some results about the  structure of the group $N/C$ and it is relation to $W$?

Many regards